# Java: how come this does not compile?

Tags: java, enums

How come this code doesnt compile?

```
class A
{
  class B
  {
    public enum Enum   <-- this line
    {
      AD,
      BC
    }
  }
}
```

Compiler reports:

```
enum declarations allowed only in static contexts.
```

But then when I put the Enum inside class A, everything is okay.

This is quite surprising. I dont think I have this problem in C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this by making B static:

```
static class B { ...
```

This mirrors more closely what C++ does with nested classes. By default (without `static`), instances of B contain a hidden reference to an instance of A.

A good explanation of the differences can be found at [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class).

Comment: An enum is an intrinsically static beast.  In the example above, you only ever want there to be one Enum.AD object.  But if you declared an enum inside a non-static class, you'd (in theory) need a different instance of Enum.AD for each synamic scope.  That doesn't make sense ... therefore it is forbidden.